# regex allow only letters, numbers, dot, underscore, dash. at least 5 characters

Tags: javascript, regex

How to make regex fit below rules

1. allow only letters (uppercase or smallcase), numbers, dot, underscore, dash
2. at least 5 characters
3. can't contain generic terms or extensions (ex: .com, .net).  .php, .mustache, .html, .js, .jpeg, .jpg, .png, .tiff, ..
   e.g.
   `username.com` x
   `username.comme` o

here's mine, fail to match if contain dot, underscore, dash,
and how to exclude extension string
`^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*\w{5,}$`

https://regex101.com/r/pT0iD8/1

Comment: Is  `example.com` acceptable?

Comment: no it contains `.com`

Comment: Then your third rule is unclear ..

Comment: thanks for reply, I update in question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It would be something like this:

```
^([\w.-](?!\.(com|net|html?|js|jpe?g|png)$)){5,}$
```

Explaining:

```
^              # from start            
([\w.-]        # \w is equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_]
    (?!\.          # in front can NOT be a dot followed by
        (com           # com
        |net           # OR net
        |html?         # OR htm or html     # ? means optional match
        |js            # OR js
        |jpe?g         # OR jpg or jpeg
        |png           # OR png
        )$             # block only if it is at the end
    )              # end of the negative lookahead
){5,}          # match at least 5 characters in above conditions
$              # till the end
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: up vote for the detailed explanation of each step and for showing OP the magic of \w

Comment: thanks for reply, I paste to `https://regex101.com/r/pT0iD8/3` but if  `username.comme` can't pass

Comment: This is not what OP wants ... `example.come`  is acceptable, but [your pattern doesn't match it](https://regex101.com/r/pT0iD8/4)

Comment: @user1575921. When I first read your question I didn't see the third rule, sorry for that... I've updated

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes Thanks so much! it work! and thanks for detail explanation!!

Comment: Shouldn't the `{5,}` be before the lookahead?

Comment: @Tracker1. No, because the literal dot is a valid character to match

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes yeah, it should work in either case... still don't care much for look aheads in regexp, that said, nice answer.

Answer (score 1):

Though you could (possibly) wrangle it into a single regexp, it would perform *really* badly... you'd be much better off using a function, that can use two 
regular expressions.

The second part may be better off with an array check, with all the values split into an array.

```
function isValid(str) {
  return (/^([\w\d_\.]{5,})$/i).test(str) 
    && !(/\.(dll|com|net|exe|php|html|js|jpeg|jpg|png|tiff|gif)$/i).test(str);
}
```

Comment: @PM77-1 look aheads in JS are particularly slow, and harder to understand inline... though arguably regex in general is hard for people to grasp...  Also, checking the characters at the end for common extensions should be separate from the allowed character check, it's really two rules.